# Vanilla JS - How to check if children contain color class, remove the actual class if it exists, then add new class?

Tags: javascript, dom-traversal, text-styling

I'm using this code:

```
if ( selectColor.value == "R" & selectDiv.value == "grandParent" ) {
  grandParent.children[0].classList.add("red")
} 
if ( selectColor.value == "R" & selectDiv.value == "parent-1" & parent1.children[0].contains('red') == false) {
  parent1.children[0].classList.add("red")
}
```

The first if statement works fine.
The second doesn't.
What I'm trying to do is check if a div has a class or not, if not, add the selected color class,if it already has a class, remove it and add the new selected class.

I couldn't get to the answer of this exact logic myself using others posts.
I'm learning with no live help for 4 months (until now) through internet courses, so bear with me if you can.

Comment: First problem: use `&&` not `&`

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, but have you looked at [`classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)?

Answer (score 4):

Let's break your problem into sub-problems:-

> Check if a div has a class or not

```js
var root = document.querySelector('.root')
console.log(root.classList.contains('root')) // returns true
console.log(root.classList.contains('hello')) // returs false
```

```html
<div class='root'></div>
```

> Add the selected colour class

```js
var myDiv = document.querySelector('#myDiv');
myDiv.classList.add('root');
console.log(myDiv);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

> Check if it already has a class

```js
var div = document.querySelector('.someClassName');
console.log(div.classList.contains('someClassName'));
```

```html
<div class="someClassName"></div>
```

> Remove the existing class

```js
var myDiv = document.querySelector('.specialClass');
console.log(myDiv); // myDiv before removal
myDiv.classList.remove('specialClass');
console.log(myDiv); //myDiv after removal
```

```html
<div class="specialClass"></div>
```

> To combine all of the above scenarios in your problem statement, which is, *What I'm trying to do is check if a div has a class or not, if not, add the selected color class,if it already has a class, remove it and add the new selected class.*

```js
var div1 = document.querySelector('.class_div1');
if(div1.classList.contains('class_div1')){
  div1.classList.remove('class_div1');
  div1.classList.add('new_selected_class');
} else {
  div1.classList.add('selected_color_class');
}

console.log(div1)
```

```html
<div class="class_div1"></div>
```